# Adding feature layer to ArcMap from url

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, feature-layer, arcgis-online

Is it possible to somehow load feature layer from REST (like: [ArcGIS Example Service](http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Petroleum/KGS_OilGasFields_Kansas/MapServer/0)) to ArcMap? No need to edit that layer, we just need to select data from it and then create a local FeatureClass.

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to know if it is possible to add data through URL, without providing any login information (like when we add layer to map in JavaScript API by providing only layer's url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a map service to ArcMap by establishing a GIS Server connection ([GIS Servers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006600000450000000) folder in the Catalog window). However, you will only be able to view the data and you cannot select any features (you can, however, use Identify tool to find out the attributes of certain features/raster pixels if the author has enabled this option). Neither can you export the data to a local geodatabase or shapefile since the geometry is not exposed.

You don't have to provide any login credentials when you connect as a user if the service's author has not secured it.

In order to be able to get the geometry+attributes of the features, the [Feature Access](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000002w8000000) capability should be enabled on the map service an organization publishes. There is a way to [check-out the feature service data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m60000000s000000) (map service with Feature Access capability enabled) in ArcMap to a local geodatabase and edit it later on. An example of such a feature service can be found [here](http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/BloomfieldHillsMichigan/LandusePlanning/MapServer).